# Merge all tags involving temp tables

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I'd like this combination to be merged:

[temptables](/questions/tagged/temptables) (109) [temp-table](/questions/tagged/temp-table) (44) [temptable](/questions/tagged/temptable) (23) [temporary-table](/questions/tagged/temporary-table) (28) [temporary-tables](/questions/tagged/temporary-tables) (360)

My preference would be a tag that actually doesn't exist currently on SO, [temp-tables](/questions/tagged/temp-tables). I prefer this one because it's shorter than "temporary-tables", reflects how most of us use the term in regular conversation, and [this is the only version of any of these otherwise identical tags that we have on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/temp-tables).

But honestly I don't care which one is chosen - that would just make it consistent between the two sites. More importantly we should just have one tag that covers all of these, regardless of what it is.

I've seen [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135985/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags), which just seems to be a massive, insurmountable laundry list of tag merges, dealing only with plural vs. singular forms, and I think this is a prevalent enough scenario to be handled outside of that work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it shall be.

*waves hands in a magical motion*

Comment: Wow, easiest meta request ever. Thanks!

Comment: Whoever says Meta isn't easy is lying.